Altering Iceberg table data using Spark SQL
I am creating tables in Iceberg using Spark with Rest Catalog and saving the data in MinIO. I wish to Update /or Delete any row data based on ID column. There are no direct methods to apply this, so I am using the following methods:
UPDATE TABLE
-- Original Table (default.ns.tbl)
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | one  | two  | three|
+----+------+------+------+
| 2  | one  | two  | three|
+----+------+------+------+
| 3  | one  | two  | three|
+----+------+------+------+

-- Row to update formed as another table (default.ns.temp)
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 1  | ten  | ten  | seven|
+----+------+------+------+

--Update command
INSERT INTO default.ns.tbl REPLACE WHERE ID = 1 SELECT * FROM default.ns.temp

--Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS default.ns.temp PURGE

DELETE COMMAND
INSERT OVERWRITE default.ns.tbl FROM default.ns.tbl WHERE ID != 1

Now the issue with both Update is that it needs to create a temporary table and delete it, so every update command might become slow because of it; and the issue with Delete is that it still retains the data of earlier snapshots, thus increasing the size of the MinIO bucket.
How can I run Update and Delete commands to run in place?

@Luuk Yes it is not used for deleting, but I have used it for the purpose of deleting. I am overwriting the same table with a filter command, so the resultant data will have that particular row deleted

Can you share more details on what this INSERT OVERWRITE default.ns.tbl FROM default.ns.tbl WHERE ID != 1 is doing (I only know SQL, not spark-sql). It seems to me that, with the given data, nothing changes.

@Luuk If I take the command SELECT * FROM default.ns.tbl WHERE ID != 1, it will give me only the rows where ID is not 1. The INSERT OVERWRITE command of spark-sql overwrites any table saved in database with the table provided. So, my delete command is actually taking all the rows where ID is not 1, and then overwriting the current data with this filtered data. Thus, effectively it is deleting the data from the table

The Spark SQL documentation is incomplete.
There are straightforward methods for UPDATE and DELETE, just like regular SQL.
